# smart phone bratinger app

Tags: android

I want to make an android application that when it reaches a predefined  GPS location , it will do an action(send message or play sound )

I can make a background service that will run in the background, but while surfing the internet I found this app http://smartphone.bartinger.at/

where you can set conditions and adjust the settings when this condition is met. It said on the website that
"isn´t just a background service that constantly checks if the conditions apply. Nearly all conditions are handled by features of Android. Smart Phone is using these features, so they don’t need to run in the background and won’t drain your battery."

So clearly my question is , ift's not background service so what is it ? What does it mean that I am programming the features ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: SO is not a research service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right: if you run a service that checks every time if a condition is met, you will drain the battery (depending of the checks of course). That's why you should use BroadcastReceivers if you can. 
Take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html). Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to run background service to check for user location update. Go through [LocationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) class and call proper variant of requestLocationUpdate for your scenario it will notify when location changes, in LocationListener you can differentiate whether the location is of your interest or not.